# What's the language rule behind converting a string type to byte slice and what's actually being done in this conversion?

Tags: string, go

It's ok and even sounds logical to convert string type to byte slice in Go, as seen in the example below (`[]byte(s)`).

The question is what's the rule behind this conversion? where is this conversion defined to make it applicable? Also, what's behind this conversion, meaning, what's being done behind the scenes? Couldn't find it in `builtin.go`.

Working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "A string"
    myBytes := []byte(s) // The conversion
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(myBytes)
}
```

If I replace the `[]byte(s)` with `[]int(s)` it fails on `cannot convert s (type string) to type []int`, which I understand as `int` is not `uint8/byte`. This means that the conversion is specific, so where is the specificity defined?

Comment: It’s defined in the language specification. It’s allowed because the specification says it’s allowed.

Comment: The semantics of a string-byteslice-conversion is natural and welldefined (as converting to rune slice).

Comment: Take note of the `builtin` docs, that package doesn’t define anything: “Package builtin provides documentation for Go's predeclared identifiers. The items documented here are not actually in package builtin”.

Comment: Can you please send a link to the spec where the conversion is allowed?

Comment: Conversions are all covered under [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

Comment: Thanks JimB. From the spec under [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions): "A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:...x is a string and T is a slice of bytes or runes."

Comment: How is this question opinion-based? It's a question about a specific language feature, trying to understand it and find it's definition. Anyhow, change the question to try to be less specific. @JimB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in where this happens in the Go compiler/runtime, check out the `runtime.stringtoslicebyte` function: https://golang.org/src/runtime/string.go?s=4341:4393#L155

A call to this function is generated by the compiler (try running `go tool compiler -l -S <your-go-file.go>` to see it)

[note that this is true for the time of writing, in Go 1.15, and may change in the future]

Comment: Thanks Eli. As JimB stated, from the spec PoV, under [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions): "A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:...x is a string and T is a slice of bytes or runes."

Comment: In the code, I see `copy(b, s)`, so does this mean that if the size of the string is `n`, the complexity of the conversion is `O(n)`? Is so, this is quite surprising as a seamless naive conversion is actually a full blown copy.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so a copy is required in the general case. The compiler may make other optimizations and not necessarily call that particular function in all cases.